Cliping netcdf with shapefile
I want to clip netcdf with shapefile but keep getting errors. I also tried to project it to the same coordinate system, but it seems not to be working. Can you please help me?
import xarray
import geopandas
from shapely.geometry import mapping
import glob

 # File paths
shapefile = 'Basin.shp'
netcdf_pattern = r"C:Surface runoff\qtot_new.nc"

# Find matching netCDF files
file_list = sorted(glob.glob(netcdf_pattern))

if not file_list:
    print("No netCDF files found matching the pattern:", netcdf_pattern)
else:
    print("Found the following netCDF files:")
    for file in file_list:
        print(file)

# Read shapefile
sf = geopandas.read_file(shapefile)

# Set CRS for shapefile
sf.set_crs('epsg:4326', inplace=True, allow_override=True)

for file in file_list:
    # Open netCDF file using the 'netcdf4' engine
    nc_file = xarray.open_dataset(file, engine='netcdf4')

    # Set CRS for netCDF files
    nc_file.rio.write_crs('epsg:4326', inplace=True)`your text`

    # Clip netCDF file using latitude and longitude
    clipped_nc = nc_file.rio.clip(sf.geometry.apply(mapping), sf.crs, all_touched=True)`

